# VBA Form to Only Calculate once 3 textboxes are filled

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I have a VBA form with 4 textboxes, the first starts populated with a value, the remaining 3 will start blank. My goal is to have the formula run only when all 3 are greater than zero or "", and recalculate on subsequent changes, provided again that all 3 have values. I found a slightly similar thread for this but it was on Java, not VBA. This is what I have so far. I've tried IF functions and it still throws an error. Thank you!

```
Option Explicit

Public RTempFormP As Double

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

RTempFormP = Range("RPress1")
TextBox1 = RTempFormP

End Sub
Private Sub TextBox2_AfterUpdate()

Call RunTemp

End Sub
Private Sub TextBox3_AfterUpdate()

Call RunTemp

End Sub
Private Sub TextBox4_AfterUpdate()

Call RunTemp

End Sub

Sub RunTemp()
Dim CoeffA As Double: CoeffA = TextBox2
Dim CoeffB As Double: CoeffB = TextBox3
Dim CoeffC As Double: CoeffC = TextBox4
Dim RTempFormT As Double

RTempFormT = CoeffB / (CoeffA - Log10(RTempFormP * 14.5)) - CoeffC

Label7 = (9 / 5) * (RTempFormT - 273.15) + 32

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to test to see if they have numeric values before you assign them to a `Double`. After that, if should just be `If Not CoeffA > 0 Then Exit Sub` or something to that effect.  Note that you should also test that `(CoeffA - Log10(RTempFormP * 14.5)) - CoeffC` is not 0

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to run those logical checks, assign them to the variables, and associate them with the sub in question, I'm kind of a novice to programming. I can check with a friend when we get a chance to meet up, I didn't know if this was something with a simple solution, but I'm not out to put anyone through a lot of work. Thanks!